# Do i need to handle null on getClassLoader() before calling getResource()

Tags: java

I have class named MyClass, and inside the class i am calling  `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("SCHEMA.xsd")`. When i run fortify scan on this code, it complains me to handle null on `MyClass.class.getClassLoader()` before calling `getResource()`. Do i really need to handle null here? under what scenarios `getClassLoader()` will return null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Javadoc

> Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader. [...] If this object represents a primitive type or void, null is returned.

If you don't use any framework you should be safe most of the time. See the doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader()

**Edit**: corrected with comment from @mangotang

Comment: The javadoc also says `Some implementations may use null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap class loader.`